# How to identify whether a function is called as method or callback

Tags: javascript

I have an object which has a method. This method can be triggered as method on object or as callback function. What is the best way to determine how it's called? I've come up with a solution that I'm not sure is relible.

```
function Object() {
    this.method = function(elem) {
        if (elem.type !== undefined) {
            alert("we've got an event");
        } else {
            alert("it doens's seem to be an event");
        }
    }
}
var obj = new Object();
$('span').click(obj.method);
obj.method($('div'));
```

I've decided to edit my question a bit to point out that the question is not about 'this' parameter and how to bind function's context.

Comment: Don't actually name your object `Object`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat that too.

Comment: If a function is invoked as a method, its 'this' property should be the object. If it is passed as an argument (i.e. as a callback), its 'this' property should be the window.

Comment: @xiaodili that is not true at all.

Comment: @xiaodili: `this` can be changed using `.call`.

Comment: @xiaodili In this particular case (i.e., jQuery `click` callback), `this` is set to the element that is the target of the click. In general, when a function calls a callback, it can set the callback's `this` using `call` (or, more obtusely, by attaching the callback to an object as a method and invoking it).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it should matter how the code was called.  I bet that if you can articulate why it does matter, you'll see there's a parameter that should be passed to the function that lets the function know this.  Then you could make a simple wrapper that will do it appropriately:

```
function MyObject() {
    this.method = function(randomParam1, randomParam2, calledThroughAlert) {
        // calledThroughAlert knows what you need to know.
    }
}

function callbackToMyObject() {
    obj.method('foo', 'bar', true);
}
var obj = new MyObject();
$('span').click(callbackToMyObject);
obj.method('bar', 'foo'); // defaults the calledThroughAlert param to false
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just about jQuery stuff (e.g. $.click), you could check if the event itself is passed to the function:

```
var handleClick = function () {
    var $this = $(this); // obj

    if (arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] instanceof jQuery.Event) {
        alert('called as callback');
    } else {
        alert('called directly');
    }
};

$('button').click(handleClick);
handleClick();
```

Comment: Thanks, this probably should work, but it's limited to jQuery stuff only.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` inside `method` will be the `Object` instance (see Rocket's comment about naming) for all intents and purposes (unless the value was purposefully set via `bind()`, `call()` or `apply()`).

When executed as a method, the value of `this` will be the `Object` instance (again, unless altered via `bind()`, `call()` or `apply()`).

```
function Object() {
    var that = this;

    this.method = function(elem) {
        if (this !== that) {
            alert("we've got an event");
        } else {
            alert("it doens's seem to be an event");
        }
    }
}
```

You can see this working [here http://jsfiddle.net/5WzEA/](http://jsfiddle.net/5WzEA/).

Comment: Nope... Sorry, not true **at all**

Comment: @Neal: Did you read me post? "unless the value was purposefully set via `bind()`, `call()` or `apply()`". In the OP's code and question, no use of these methods were specified, so I bet it'll work damn fine.

Comment: ... furthermore in that jsFiddle you *are* calling `method` as a method, and passing the *result* of that to the click handler. I think you meant http://jsfiddle.net/5WzEA/2/, but meh.

Answer (score 0):

You should just have 2 different methods if they do different things.

If you really have the method do the same thing regardless of if it's called
as a method or a callback, you can use `$.proxy` so that `this` is always the object:

```
function Object() {
    this.method = $.proxy( function(){

    }, this );
}
var obj = new Object();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works. Pretty close to what you had.

```
function Object() {
    this.method = function(elem) {
        console.log(elem)
        if (elem.length != 0 && elem instanceof jQuery.Event) {
            alert("Accessed on Click");
        } else {
            alert("Not accessed on click.");
        }
    }
}
var obj = new Object();


$('span').click(obj.method);  // Accessed on click.


obj.method($('div')); // Not accesed on click.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dietrichg/3mELA/

Comment: Thanks, `instanceof Jquery.Event` is really good option if I'm bound to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to determine if this is a callback is to register a different function as the callback and explicitly pass down a value to say it was indeed a callback

```
function Object() {
    this.method = function(elem, isCallback) {
        if (isCallback) { 

        }
    } 
}

var obj = new Object();
$('span').click(function (elem) { obj.method(elem, isCallback); });
obj.method($('div'));
```

Comment: This is poor use of a closure function.  Using closures open like this will lead to excessive memory consumption of your application, preventing it from scaling.

Comment: @Craig such blanket statements about performance are almost always incorrect.  This is a *single* extra function object.  It will have almost no noticable effect on the program.  Sure if i did this a few thousand times it could start adding up, just as if the OP had allocated a few thousand `Object` instances that would have a perf impact.  Neither of us did though.

Comment: This closure encapsulates a copy of the 'Object()' prototype.  If this prototype was a complex prototype, you would have one copy of the prototype per click handler created, consuming more memory than you would imagine.  As well as a copy of an instance of the prototype via the 'obj' variable.

Comment: @Craig now you are making a correctness argument and not a perf one.  Yes it is possible that if `Object` is defined in a global context and this code is run more than once that I might have an inadvertent capture.  The OP did not provide the full context here but my assumption was this code ran once.  Now, your original comment was that I had created a perf problem.  You haven't said anything to back that up yet (and if it is a prob, then your answer has it as well)

Comment: @JaredPar, I guess using closure is the best option here since it is not bound to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind a function to a context (object), then use something like this:

```
function createOnClick(obj, fn) {
    return function() {
        return fn.apply(obj, arguments);
    }
}

myObject = new Object();

$('button').click(createOnClick(myObject, myObject.method));
```

Now, when your method is called, 'this' will be a reference to the 'myObject' instance.  This is commonly known and function binding and there are many API's that already do this.  However, I am unfamiliar with JQuery, so you will need to refer to the documentation.

Comment: You commented that I was carelessly allocating a closure yet your code does the *exact* same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this option is even better:
I remove the check from the method and always expect an element to be passed. As a callback I pass the function that takes 'this' which will be a reference to the element and passes to my method:

```
$('span').click(function(){obj.method(this)};
```